# For Loop One Too Long

Tags: r

I've coded a function that converts an atomic symbol to an atomic number ...

```
AtomicNo  <- function(x) {
  y  <- NULL
  for (i in seq(along=x)) {
    if (x[i] == "H") y[i]  <- 1.0 else
      if (x[i] == "C") y[i]  <- 6.0 else
        if (x[i] == "O") y[i]  <- 8.0 else
          if (x[i] == "Fe") y[i]  <- 26.0 else
            if (x[i] == "Br") y[i]  <- 35.0
    y  <- append(y,y[i])
  }
    return(y)
  }
```

For vector

```
a <- c("Fe", "Br", "O", "O", "C", "H", "H", "H", "C", "H", "H", "H", 
        "C", "H", "H", "H", "C", "H", "H", "H")
```

AtomicNo(a) gives

```
26 35  8  8  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  1
```

That is, there is an extra 1 at the end of the vector, there should only be three 1s rather than four.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple recoding you can use vector indexing along with giving elements names

```
code <- c("H" = 1.0, "C" = 6.0, "O" = 8.0, "Fe" = 26.0, "Br" = 35.0)
a <- c("Fe", "Br", "O", "O", "C", "H", "H", "H", "C", "H", "H", "H", "C", "H", "H", "H", "C", "H", "H", "H") 
code[a]
#Fe Br  O  O  C  H  H  H  C  H  H  H  C  H  H  H  C  H  H  H 
#26 35  8  8  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1 
## If you don't want the names...
unname(code[a])
# [1] 26 35  8  8  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1
```

Edit:

As for why you're getting the additional 1 on the end - it has to do with your code.  Take a look at the first few iterations unwrapped

```
> y <- NULL
> y[1] <- 26
> y <- append(y, y[1])
> y
[1] 26 26
> y[2] <- 35
> y <- append(y, y[2])
> y
[1] 26 35 35
```

Basically you're directly setting the last element and then also deciding to append it to the end.  In the next iteration that appended element will get overwritten but for the very last iteration there isn't anything to overwrite the additional element at the end so you end up with a duplicate value for the last.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using multiple `ifelse`, you could simply do:

```
elements <- c("H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb", "Lu", "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "Ac", "Th", "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "Lr", "Rf", "Db", "Sg", "Bh", "Hs", "Mt", "Ds", "Rg", "Cn", "Uut", "Fl", "Uup", "Lv", "Uus", "Uuo")
```

(it's useful for a chemist to have the list of elements anyways)

and then:

```
> match(a,elements)
 [1] 26 35  8  8  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1
```

Here is benchmark:

```
> microbenchmark(f.match(big.a), atomic.recode(big.a), atomic.ifelse(big.a))
Unit: microseconds
                 expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
       f.match(big.a)   205.090   252.345   280.8174   279.556   305.683   384.358   100 a  
 atomic.recode(big.a)  7689.944  8123.826  8622.3087  8295.475  8583.322 14963.013   100  b 
 atomic.ifelse(big.a) 21804.622 23092.946 24446.9123 24041.193 25475.073 29158.469   100   c
```

(where `f.match <- function(x) match(x,elements)`)

Comment: Ah just added it to my benchmark -- I hadn't seen that you had added it here as well.

Comment: Thanks for that one, @josilber--it's always good to see that results are reproducible

Answer (score 5):

You might find it easier (or at least less typing) to use the `recode` function from the car package:

```
library(car)
recode(a, "'H'=1;'C'=6;'O'=8;'Fe'=26;'Br'=35;")
# [1] 26 35  8  8  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1  6  1  1  1
```

If you want to stay in base R, then you will find the `ifelse` function to be a good deal more efficient with very similar syntax:

```
atomic.ifelse <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x == "H", 1,
    ifelse(x == "C", 6,
      ifelse(x == "O", 8,
        ifelse(x == "Fe", 26,
          ifelse(x == "Br", 35, NA)))))
}
```

`recode`, `ifelse`, and `match` should be a good deal more efficient than a `for` loop with an `if` statement (adding `atomic.if` from @CactusWoman, `atomic.match` from @MaratTalipov, and `atomic.index` from @Dason):

```
big.a <- rep(a, 1000)
all.equal(atomic.if(big.a), atomic.recode(big.a), atomic.ifelse(big.a), atomic.match(big.a), atomic.index(big.a))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(atomic.if(big.a), atomic.recode(big.a), atomic.ifelse(big.a), atomic.match(big.a), atomic.index(big.a))
# Unit: microseconds
#                  expr        min          lq        mean      median         uq         max neval
#      atomic.if(big.a) 753887.018 823974.2900 887305.3812 876902.6380 924005.505 1836067.802   100
#  atomic.recode(big.a)   8748.951   9129.5230  10694.0044   9299.0145   9617.688  116548.870   100
#  atomic.ifelse(big.a)  26329.875  27568.6540  30005.9327  28635.7760  29652.327  133560.908   100
#   atomic.match(big.a)    210.846    257.7595    370.9925    296.4305    343.732    2434.733   100
#   atomic.index(big.a)    527.043    616.7620   1013.0317    876.6060   1077.634    3371.246   100
```

The vectorization of `recode`, `ifelse`, `match`, and vector indexing have provided speedups of 30-3000x over the `for` loop even on this relatively small vector (length 20,000). `match` and vector indexing appear to be the winners in terms of efficiency (15-30x faster than `recode`), so that would be the way to go for very large vectors.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to append y at the end of your function. Just remove that and you should be fine

```
AtomicNo  <- function(x) {
  y  <- NULL
  for (i in seq(along=x)) {
    if (x[i] == "H") y[i]  <- 1.0 else
      if (x[i] == "C") y[i]  <- 6.0 else
        if (x[i] == "O") y[i]  <- 8.0 else
          if (x[i] == "Fe") y[i]  <- 26.0 else
            if (x[i] == "Br") y[i]  <- 35.0
  }
  return(y)
}
```